# Where can log4net write log files that is compatible with XP, Vista, and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, log4net

I have a C#.NET 4.0 app that uses log4net for logging. Under Windows XP, it's always written log files to *System.Windows.Forms.Application.CommonAppDataPath*, and this works for admin users under Windows 7 as well, even with UAC set to its default level. When running as a limited user under Windows 7 with UAC at the same level, however, the log files don't get written to.

Is there a way to get log4net to access those same rolling log files when running as a limited user, or am I forced to use *System.Windows.Forms.Application.UserAppDataPath* instead and have different log files for each user? I'd prefer to have a single set of rolling log files for all users if possible, as it makes customer support much easier.

Finally, the program must run "asInvoker," so elevating the app isn't an option.

Comment: Is it proper to assume you would not want to just create a folder for log4net to write to?  For example, when the application installs on the machine, you could create a new folder on the root of the primary drive and call it "logfiles" or something like that.  Is that not an option?

Comment: That might be an option. I could also consider making that folder be a sub-folder of CommonAppDataPath. As long as the only thing in there is the log files, I don't think that should be a problem from a security standpoint. We have some very paranoid customers from a security standpoint, so we're pretty restricted in where we can put world-writable folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a variation on sgmoore's suggestion. I created a folder called C:\ProgramData\[CompanyName]\[ProductName]\logs, on which I enabled write access for the local Users group. This has the advantage of keeping minimal access for all other files in ProgramData while giving the necessary access on *just the log files* for those who need it.

Comment: I assume you don't have malicious users in your circumstances, because it also means that any user can destroy any and all logs.

Comment: Yes, we're assuming that. It's a desktop app that runs on an instrument controller computer in a lab and on researchers' desktop systems, so we're generally not worried about malicious users. Since the logs are generally only read by our service technicians during field support visits for diagnostic purposes, destroyed log files wouldn't be a total disaster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the permissions on the folder c:\programdata\xxx (where xxx is your company name) to enable write access for everyone?

Comment: That had occurred to me, but I'd prefer to avoid messing with permissions on the app's folder in ProgramData, as that seems to violate the spirit of UAC.